Необходимость валидации дублирующихся данных в json
REST API Метод должен принимать некий json. Стоит ли считать ошибкой валидации, если в json, который приходит на вход, происходит дублирование данных?
Пример входных данных:
{
  "id": 15,
  "id": 16
}

Должен быть только один id. Вопрос в том, что бэку как бы все равно, сколько дублей придет, он сможет корректно отработать запрос, взяв в обработку первый. С другой стороны, налицо, явная неоднозначность, потому что неясно, какой id фронт имел ввиду. Как будто бы - противоречие ограничению REST, когда запросы должны быть составлены таким образом, чтобы сервер однозначно мог понять, что за ресурс запрашивает клиент. Или ошибаюсь?

А как фронт смог пихнуть 2 одинаковых ключа в объект? И как бэк это распарсил? Вручную строкой, без конвертации?

Этот кейс вытащили тестировщики как баг. Бэк считает, что все норм. Не знаю точно, как они это распарсивают, но знаю, что как-то берут первое значение. Тестировщики закидывали многократно дублирующиеся пары ключ-значение, и ответ был 200.

Я за тестировщиков :)

Вопрос в том, насколько такой запрос на практике возможен. Если фронт такое действительно может отправить, то нужно валидировать. Если возможен только если постманом или курлом такой кривой json отправлять, то не нужно.

С точки зрения стандарта это невалидный json. С практической точки зрения, такое лучше не допускать потому что завтра у вас появится ещё один сервер который будет брать не первый id, а последний и привет какая-нибудь уязвимость. Так что безопаснее сразу запретить невалидный json

@AlexeyTen нет, оба известных мне стандарта json не запрещают делать дублирующиеся ключи

@andreymal Но ведь это же аналог словаря, как в словаре могут быть два одинаковых ключа?

@andreymal согласен, формально не запрещает а всего лишь «SHOULD be unique». Именно по той причине что я описал. У автора бекенд берёт первый id, а например JSON.parse в JS берёт последний. Ну и исходя из оригинального желания что JSON это валидный объект в JS (хотя это в результате оказалось неверно) тоже не стоит так делать.

@andreymal мастодонты обсуждали 11 лет назад, но так ни к чему и не пришли https://esdiscuss.org/topic/json-duplicate-keys

Я бы считал ошибкой, потому что да - как минимум неоднозначность.
import json

data = """
{
  "id": 15,
  "id": 16
}
"""

print(json.loads(data))

# {'id': 16}

Питон заполняет словари по правилу "последующие повторяющиеся ключи перебивают предыдущие".
На английском SO есть вопрос с ответами и обсуждениями, там есть ссылки на стандарты.
Вкратце там такие выводы:

Стандарт такое не запрещает, но и не рекомендует
Такая структура данных порождает неоднозначность поведения:

могут прочитаться оба ключа
прочитается один ключ - первый
прочитается один ключ - последний
либо вообще может выйти ошибка библиотеки, которая будет такой JSON загружать.



Считать ли неопределённость в данных ошибкой валидации - это уже на ваше усмотрение. Я бы лично считал ошибкой, потому что стандарт это конечно хорошо, но его конкретные реализации такое не любят.
